# Remove background color of the space between menu items in a CSS menu

Tags: css

I need my menu items to show up with some space between them, so I use a right margin of `13px`.

But, then, the `background-color` is the same as it is for the anchor tag. Instead I need the `background-color` to only apply to the list/anchor elements, and not the margin space inbetween.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="title">
        Vanneuville <br />
        Wielersport
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Fietsen</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Recreationeel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Electrische fietsen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Koersfietsen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mountainbikes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kinderfietsen</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Kledij</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Helmen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tweedehands</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Verhuur</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="clear" id="content">
        <p>Some paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body
 {
background: url('../images/peloton.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover; /*for webKit*/
-moz-background-size: cover; /*Mozilla*/
-o-background-size: cover; /*opera*/
background-size: cover; /*generic*/
font-family: "Cambria";
}

#container{
width: 1000px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto
 }

#title{
display: inline-block;
font-size: 80px;
background-color: black;
color: white;
opacity: 0.8;
padding: 15px;
float:left;
}

#menu{
float:left;
padding-top: 10px;
font-size: 31px;
}

#content{
padding-top: 10px;
background-color: red;
background-clip: content-box;
}

.clear{
clear: both;
}

ul{
list-style-type: none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

ul#nav li{
background: grey;
float: left;
}

ul#nav li a{
display: block;
padding: 5px 10px;
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
margin-right: 13px;
}

ul#nav li a:hover{
background: #aaa;
}

ul#nav li ul li{
float: none;
}

ul#nav li ul{
position: absolute;
display: none;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul{
display: block;
}
```

Comment: I want some space between my buttons.

Comment: Remove the background colour from the li and add it to the anchor

Comment: This solved my - rather stupid - problem!

Comment: @Stijn Hoste no worries

Comment: @StijnHoste Remember to accept 3rror's answer if it helped!

Comment: @Zenith You are a gentleman :)

Comment: How can I accept a comment?

Answer (score 3):

Move your background colour declaration from the `li` to the `anchor`

```
ul#nav li{
    float: left;
}

ul#nav li a{
    background: grey;
}
```